# Gettin Parser Error while installing Package in Julia 1.0.1

Tags: julia

When I tried to run Pkg.add('BenchmarkTools") I got the following error.

```
ERROR: Pkg.TOML.ParserError(3, 4, "expected `=`, but found `\x90`")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a general problem. The only solution for this is to close julia or coding environment, delete the TOML file in
C:\Users<USER>.julia\logs
and restart Julia

Comment: If it solved your problem, maybe you should accept your own answer.